# Getting Internal server error, Permission denied running cgi under apache on centos linux

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi, selinux

The usual Internal Server Error with More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

selinux is enforcing but noting listed in logs(I did allow but I can't find it in history but I think it was semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/data/srv/www(/.*)?'  and restorecon -RFvv /data/srv/www
Verified the httpd deamon is runing as apache and it's group is apache. (with ps -ef|grep httpd and id apache)

Permissions all the way up look good

[root@bilbo public_html]# ls -l /data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi;

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user apache 208 Oct  8 02:34 /data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi
# ls -dl /data/srv/www/public_html/ /data/srv/www/ /data/srv/ /data/srv/ /data/ 
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root     97 Oct  8 00:26 /data/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user apache   17 Oct  7 23:34 /data/srv/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user apache   17 Oct  7 23:34 /data/srv/
drwxr-xr-x.  7 user apache  167 Oct  8 01:40 /data/srv/www/
drwxr-xr-x. 19 user apache 4096 Oct  8 02:34 /data/srv/www/public_html/
```

My Config file

[root@bilbo public_html] # cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/domainname.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.bilbo
    ServerAlias www.domainname.bilbo domainname.bilbo.middleearth www.domainname.bilbo.middleearth
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /data/srv/www/public_html

    <Directory /data/srv/www/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.php
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domainname.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domainname.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[root@bilbo public_html]# tail /var/log/httpd/domainname.com-error.log

```
[Fri Oct 08 09:39:06.491759 2021] [cgid:error] [pid 1204081:tid 139698072696576] [client 10.0.0.10:57760] AH01241: error spawning CGI child: exec of '/data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi' failed (Permission denied): /data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi
[Fri Oct 08 09:39:06.492344 2021] [cgid:error] [pid 1204081:tid 139698072696576] [client 10.0.0.10:57760] End of script output before headers: test.cgi
```

## cat /data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "hello w\n";
```

## sudo -u apache /data/srv/www/public_html/test.cgi

```
Content-type: text/html

hello w
```

Checking the modules

[root@bilbo public_html]# grep -v "^#" /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-cgi.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
   LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```

[root@bilbo public_html] # egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

Well I was pulling my hair, but for grins and giggles I disabled selinux (setenforce 0) and tried, and it worked.....
So after going wtf, I enabled selinux (setenforce 1)

This is what I put in (IIRC) to make it work

```
# semanage fcontext -m -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/data/srv/www(/.*)?'
# restorecon -RFvv /data/srv/www
```

So yea, no longs in /var/log/messages and nothing in sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log to suggest selinux was blocking anything....

Answer (score 2):

Well I was pulling my hair, but for grins and giggles I disabled selinux (setenforce 0) and tried, and it worked..... So after going wtf, I enabled selinux (setenforce 1)

This is what I put in (IIRC) to make it work

```
# semanage fcontext -m -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/data/srv/www(/.*)?'
# restorecon -RFvv /data/srv/www
```

So yea, no longs in /var/log/messages and nothing in sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log to suggest selinux was blocking anything....